# Contents of list of unique_ptr are inaccessible

Tags: c++, list, unique-ptr

I've got a `std::list` of `std::unique_ptrs` to `Entity` objects. When I try to loop through them as such, the program says that the items within the list are inaccessible. The list is a member variable, declared as private: list< unique_ptr >.

```
void EntityContainer::E_Update(int delta)
{
    for (auto& child : children)
        child->Update(delta);
}
```

Where `Update()` is a public function of Entity. However, upon compiling, I get the following error:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(617): error C2248: `'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr'` : cannot access private member declared in class `'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Comment: Try using references: `unique_ptr<Entity>& child : children`. You're attempting to copy the unique_ptrs.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to copy the `unique_ptr`. They can't be copied, only moved.

In the first case, use a reference:

```
for (auto const & child : children) {
    child->Update(delta);
}
```

In the second case, use the dereferenced iterator directly:

```
for (auto child = children.begin(); child != children.end(); ++child) {
   (*child)->Render();
}
```

or, if you really want a separate variable, make it a reference:

```
unique_ptr<Entity> const & childPtr = *child;
```

I understand that there's a proposal for a new form of range-based `for` loop which will access the elements by reference:

```
for (child : children) {
    child->Update(delta);
}
```

but that doesn't officially exist yet.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! Damn copy construction... I remember now that the std library must have written the copy constructor privately to avoid client misuse, hence the inaccessibility errors. Cheers.

Comment: Hm... didn't work entirely. Error is now in compilation. See above edit.

Comment: @Tedium: It looks like you're still trying to copy a pointer. Are you sure you changed your code to use references?

Comment: Yeah, I have. I'll edit the original post and remove the bad code to reduce confusion.